# Rough RPM idle transition when AC is ON

Tags: ac, rpm, kia, picanto

I have Kia Picanto 2017. I noticed that when I'm driving and depress the clutch (say would switch to neutral to stop for a red light), normally the RPM should go down to the "normal" idle level but for some reason the RPM go down below the normal RPM level 400-500 and which makes cabin to vibrate and some annoying sound can be heard then in few seconds it will kick back up to 900-1000 RPM which is the normal when the vehicle is in neutral.

I already reported this to the dealer and they did the following:

- Check for vacuum leaks but nothing was found
- Clean up throttle body - *didn't help*
- Changed spark plugs - *didn't help*
- Upgrade the ECU - *didn't help*
- Changed battery - *didn't help*
- Changed air filter - *didn't help*

For the past years I been complaining to the dealer but they always say that there's no issue or they can't find any issue. I even took a video and send them but still they can't find the issue.

Any idea with this? I notice "vibration" is getting stronger and more annoying...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You said you cleaned the throttle body ... did you completely clean the IAC and EGR valves/passages as well?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it didn't do the throttle body clean up personally. I always asked the dealer (Kia) service to do the checkup and they said they did clean up the throttle body. They didn't mention about the IAC and EGR valve.

Comment: Both the IAC (Idle Air Control) and EGR (Exhaust Gas Recirculation) valves can cause problems at idle if they are not working correctly. I'm not saying have them replaced, but rather inspected and cleaned.